# Load a web page into a Web Page Viewer web part using a link in other Web Page Viewer

Tags: page-viewer-web-part

I have two Web Part Viewers in a SharePoint 2010 web page. I will call them WPV-A and WPV-B.
WPV-A contains a simple web page with links and I need to know if it is possible to load web pages in WPV-B dynamically depending on the link clicked in WPV-A.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before over on stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161459/load-page-in-an-iframe-from-a-link-inside-another-iframe

The main difference here is you will need to lookup your iframe names since the page viewer webpart automatically creates those for you.